# missing "pass" in view

Tags: python, xml, linux, web2py

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET}}
<h1>
    This is a Stations detail page
</h1>
{{filename = xmlfile}}
{{fh = open(filename, "r")}}
{{while True:}}
    {{line = fh.readline()}}
    {{print(line, end="")}}
{{fh.close()}}
{{=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}
```

The above code is showing "missing "pass" in view" error in web2py. Not sure why this error is showing up

Comment: It looks like you have a ***lot*** of logic in what should be a relatively simple template.

Comment: Could you please describe some more detail. I am just sending file name from controller and opening and printing the file in view page.
Please suggest how should be my logic?

Comment: First, you should try to move more of your logic to the controller. Second, instead of reading each line, just read the whole file. Third, don't use `print()`. Instead of the above, in the controller, just do something like `xml_string = open(filename, 'r').read()`, and in the view include `{{=XML(xml_string)}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike in real Python, the indentation in a web2py view is only aesthetic. You need to clearly specify where the `while` block ends by adding `pass` at its end. Also note that you don't need to constantly close and open the brackets like this, you can escape all the code in only one `{{ ... }}`.

```
{{
filename = xmlfile
fh = open(xmlfile, "r")
while True:
    line = fh.readline()
    print(line, end="")
pass
fh.close()
}}
```

[More informations about web2py views here.](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views)